# Facebook Api - Local development, Testserver, Liveserver ... How?

Tags: facebook, api, testing, localhost

I'm working on a new website that uses the Facebook API for users to login and several implementations of the graph Api.

My workflow usually is:

- Development on localhost
  Development using MAMP/XAMPP or similar software
- Push to server -> testing domain
  A team of people can test the changes for a few days to see if everything works as planned.
- Push to server -> live domain
  Changes are live for public

Facebook uses the site URL in the appsettings and for security reasons, they will only redirect to that url... Problem is.. I have localhost and 2 different domains. How can I make this work?

Of course I could edit the hostsfile, but that only fixes it for localhost.. Still no solution for the testdomain.

Please tell me this is somehow possible! I'm getting more and more depressed with the Facebook API.

Answer (score 3):

I usually register a facebook app per environment. (dev points to localhost etc..)
Haven't found a nicer way to do this either..

Comment: Thanks, actually I was thinking about doing this as well. Registering the development server as a new Facebook app.
Seems to be the only solution at the moment, I can't believe Facebook isn't making this easier on developers, pretty vital function imho.

Answer (score 1):

why still test facebook api on localhost?

You can try in `heroku`

This is 
[facebook official blog article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558)

Also see the [document in heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook)

It is free to use.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Heroku, but it seems that the app will be hosted with them. We have our own servers, and our website is much more than just the facebook api/app, so I guess Heroku won't be a solution for us.